# how to use angular and JavaScript promises to return some data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, jquery-deferred, angular-promise

I am trying to grab some data from local storage, but I want to use the date once is `ready`. something like:

```
// this belongs to a Helper factory
getData: function(){
        var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function(){
            var data = {
                description: localStorageService.get('description'),
            };
            deferred.resolve()
        }, 10);
        return deferred.promise();
  },

// I set it up so that in the controller I can do
// $scope.data = Helper.getData();
```

Similar to the example i have, i just want to return the `data` object once it has the `description` from localstorage

I am using angularjs, so i want to display `{{data}}` in my view once the promise is resolved. like maybe use `ng-hide` or something similar.

In any case, my question is about setting up that promise.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sidenote, if you're using angular, don't use jQuery.Deferred, (Actually, as a general rule, don't use jQuery.Deferred) $q is a much better promise library.

Comment: @Retsam. I'm open to any good solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well `$q` is the library normally used for handling promises in angularjs, since you're reading from local storage and that is a synchronous operation I'm not sure why you want to return a promise, the way this is usually done in angular however is like this:

```
getData: function(){
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $timeout(function(){
     var data=localStorageService.get('description'),
     deferred.resolve(data);
   },3000);
   return deferred.promise;
}
```

usage:

```
getData().then(function(data){
   console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: Why `3000`, what if it takes longer to get the data?

Comment: @Patrioticcow the 3000 is just something to show you how the promised will be returned after some time, as I said though, if I'm not mistaken, reading from local storage is not an async operation, the line `var data=localStorageService.get('description'),` should return immediately, as per my experience anyway.

Comment: u heard that local storage is not an async as well, but my experience says different. maybe because the way my code is setup

Comment: @Patrioticcow I've been using [this component](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) for a while, it handles everything synchronously.

Comment: I'd recommend getting rid of the timeout.  All it does is delay how long it takes to -start- getting the data.

Comment: @Retsam Yes, I just put it there just as proof of concept regarding promises.

Answer (score 5):

$timeout() returns a promise, so this works:

```
getData: function(){
   return $timeout(function(){
       return localStorageService.get('description'),
   },3000);
}
```

usage:

```
getData().then(function(data){
   console.log(data);
})
```